# InertiaJs + Ionic response issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework, inertiajs

I am trying Inertia.js (Rails on backend) to get working with Ionic app. It actually works, but when I click Inertia link I got error message that response from server is not valid Inertia response - ***"All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received."***, however all Headers and response are look good and same app works as web app with Inertia. I can't figure out how why does Inertia consider that response not valid.

Here is error:
[image]

Response and request headers:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install `inertia_rails` gem on the backend and then
response should be like

```
render inertia: 'Event/Show',
  props: {
    event: event.as_json(
      only: [ :id, :title, :start_date, :description ]
    )
  }
```

Comment: I already installed `inertia_rails`, and controller returns right `json` response, as you can see, but inertia complains that "All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received."